# Hangout App issue with overlays

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-hangouts

It's been a week since i've got stucked in a bug using Hangouts API. I'm trying to use https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.av.effects to create an overlay when the user clicks a button.The problem I am facing is that when the user loads the app for the first time sometimes overlays work and if the user reloads the page overlays not seem to work until the overlays are loaded correctly.

Checking the Google Chrome console shows:

```
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
Unknown RPC service: hangout_effect_load_resource cb=gapi.loaded_0:98
everything ready mediaStarter.js:396
```

Moreover, the example of `https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/sample-apps` [Media App sample](https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=1054008247945) the same thing happens any help ?

My Hangout App : `https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_?gid=228838128711`